# Neo4j 2.0: Indexing array-valued properties with schema indexing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with multiple "sourceIds" in one array-valued property called "sourceIds", just because there could be multiple resources a node could be derived from (I'm assembling multiple databases into one Neo4j model).
I want to be able to look up nodes by any of their source IDs. With legacy indexing this was no problem, I would just add a node to the index associated with each element of the sourceIds property array.

Now I wanted to switch to indexing with labels and I'm wondering how that kind of index works here. I can do

```
CREATE INDEX ON :<label>(sourceIds)
```

but what does that actually do? I hoped it would just create index entries for each array element, but that doesn't seem to be the case. With

```
MATCH n:<label> WHERE "testid" in n.sourceIds RETURN n
```

the query takes between 300ms and 500ms which is too long for an index lookup (other schema indexes work three to five times faster). With

```
MATCH n:<label> WHERE n.sourceIds="testid" RETURN n
```

I don't get a result. That's clear because it's an array property but I just gave it a try since it would make sense if array properties would be broken down to their elements for indexing purposes.

So, is there a way to handle array properties with schema indexing or are there plans or will I just have to stick to legacy indexing here? My problem with the legacy Lucene index was that I hit the max number of boolean clauses (1024). Another question thus would be: Can I raise this number? Lucene allows that, but can I do this with the Lucene index used by Neo4j?

Thanks and best regards!

Edit: A bit more elaboration on why I hit the boolean clauses max limit: I need to export specific parts of the database into custom file formats for text processing pipelines. These pipelines use components I cannot (be it for the sake of accessibility or time) change to query Neo4j directly, so I'd rather stay with the defined required file format(s). I do the export via the pattern "give me all IDs in the DB; now, for batches of IDs, query the desired information (e.g. specific paths) from Neo4j and store the results to file". Why I use batches at all? Well, if I don't, things are slowed down significantly via the connection overhead. Thus, large batches are a kind of optimization here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema indexes can only do exact matches right now. Your `"testid" in n.sourceIds` does not use the index (as shown by your query times). I think there are plans to make this behave better, but I'm waiting for them just as eagerly as you are.

I've actually hit a lower max in the lucene query: 512. If there is a way to increase it I'd love to hear of it. The way I got around it is just doing more than one query if I have one of the rare cases that actually goes over 512 ids. What query are you doing where you need more?

Comment: 512? That's weird because 1024 is the Lucene default AFAIK and I assumed Neo4j just doesn't change it. This can programmatically be done on the BooleanQuery object used for the actual query. But for the Neo4j indexes, this would have to be done internally by Neo4j. I'm still on Neo4j 2.0.0-M03, perhaps the max clauses were changed in a newer version? As of my use case I edited my question, please see there.

Comment: I hit 512 in 1.9. It may be different in 2.0.

Comment: Yeah, my use case was similar in that it was a bulk operation. "which ids do I need to add as relationships to this user".

Comment: Is this still the case?  If so, can you only efficiently segment your nodes in overlapping sets using labels? ( I know you can have multiple labels and they're all effectively indexes)

Comment: Labels are a valid thing to use to make optimizations--need more details if you want better advice, though.